# Django doubling values in queryDict

Tags: python, django

I create some cascade models, double forms, and set of HTML-s with double views.py in Django. When I want to save data I get a doubling of data that has hidden input attributes.

This is from my forms.py

```
class TaskContentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    task = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Task.objects.all(),
        label="Task",
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        required=True,
    )
    position_label = forms.CharField(
        label="Position Label",
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control task_content"}),
        required=True,
    )
    position_name = forms.CharField(
        label="Position Name",
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control task"}),
        required=True,
    )
```

Models.py

```
class TaskContent(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

edit_content.html

```
<div class="row item-row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card card-body bg-white border-light shadow-sm mb-4">
      <h2 class="h5 mb-4">Transaction information</h2>
      <form action="{% url 'task_contents' task=task.id pk=task_content.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} {% if task.id %} <input type="hidden" name="task" value="{{ task.id }}"> {% endif %} <div class="row"> {% for field in form %} <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <div>{{ field.label_tag }}{{ field }}</div>
          </div> {% endfor %} </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <a class="btn btn-danger delete_item" data-href="{% url 'task_contents' task=task.id pk=task_content.id action='single' %}">Delete</a>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I press submit, I get terminal output:

```
`{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x00000203DFEC5A20>, 'id': 8, 'task_id': 4, 'position_label': '1032', 'position_name': 'Kvaka', 'material': 'Silumin', 'material_supplier': '', 'request_date': datetime.date
(2023, 5, 6), 'realization_deadline': None, 'construction_tool': '', 'tool_request_date': None, 'tool_realization_deadline': None, 'tool_creation': '', 'tool_creation_request_date': None, 'price': None}
Task: 4
Form data: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['tZ4zbHs5HeRhQHB1T4vuo66DwK5FMl7gcHyFjy3EzegHE4DsNjktlLnW9DQkDX1T'], 'task': ['4', ''], 'position_label': ['1032'], 'position_name': ['Kvaka'], 'material': ['Silumin'], 'material_s
upplier': [''], 'request_date': ['2023-05-06'], 'realization_deadline': [''], 'construction_tool': [''], 'tool_request_date': [''], 'tool_realization_deadline': [''], 'tool_creation': [''], 'tool_creation_request_date': [''], 'p
rice': ['']}>`
```

This is views.py class TaskContentView, method Update_instance responsible for rendering.

```
def update_instance(self, request, task, pk, is_urlencode=False):
    task_content = self.get_object(pk)

    print("Before form submission:")
    print(task_content.__dict__)

    task_obj = get_object_or_404(Task, id=task)
    form_data = QueryDict(request.body) if is_urlencode else request.POST

    print("Task:", task)
    print("Form data:", form_data)

    form = TaskContentForm(form_data, instance=task_content)
    if form.is_valid():
        task_content_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        task_content_instance.task = task_obj
        task_content_instance.save()

        if not is_urlencode:
            messages.success(request, "Transaction saved successfully")
        return True, "Transaction saved successfully", form

    if not is_urlencode:
        messages.warning(
            request, "Error UpdateURL Occurred. Please try again."
        )
        print(
            form.errors
        )  # Add this line to display form errors in the console
    return False, "Error Update Occurred. Please try again.", form
```

Where could be my mistake?

I wanted to make it work, but I am getting a browser error:

> Error UpdateURL Occurred. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue here. I just excluded task variable from for loop.

```
<div class="row">
                        {% for field in form %}
                            {% if field.name != 'task' %}
                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                    <div>{{ field.label_tag }}{{ field }</div>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
</div>
```